# Animate a Widget inside a DialogBox in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to animate a Layoutpanel with a textbox child inside a dialogbox. I was able to do it (i.e. the animation) when I tested it inside a simple class/view but when I imported the same code inside a dialogbox, the animation no longer works.

Basically, the animation I'm trying to accomplish is somewhat like a drawer wherein, when the user clicks on a checkbox, the layoutpanel where my textbox is, hides or unhides (like a drawer) depending on the status of the checkbox. Below is my code:

---

```
    public class Testingwork implements EntryPoint {

    private final GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT
    .create(GreetingService.class);

    private static final String SERVER_ERROR = "An error occurred while "
        + "attempting to contact the server. Please check your network "
        + "connection and try again.";

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        final Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
        final TextBox nameField = new TextBox();
        nameField.setText("GWT User");
        final Label errorLabel = new Label();

        // We can add style names to widgets
        sendButton.addStyleName("sendButton");

        // Add the nameField and sendButton to the RootPanel
        // Use RootPanel.get() to get the entire body element
        RootPanel.get("nameFieldContainer").add(nameField);
        RootPanel.get("sendButtonContainer").add(sendButton);

        RootPanel.get("errorLabelContainer").add(errorLabel);

        // Focus the cursor on the name field when the app loads
        nameField.setFocus(true);
        nameField.selectAll();

        // Create the popup dialog box
        final DialogBox dialogBox = new DialogBox();

        dialogBox.setText("Remote Procedure Call");
        dialogBox.setAnimationEnabled(true);
        final Button closeButton = new Button("Close");

        // We can set the id of a widget by accessing its Element
        closeButton.getElement().setId("closeButton");
        final Label textToServerLabel = new Label();
        final HTML serverResponseLabel = new HTML();
        VerticalPanel dialogVPanel = new VerticalPanel();
        dialogVPanel.addStyleName("dialogVPanel");
        dialogVPanel.add(new HTML("<b>Sending name to the server:</b>"));
        dialogVPanel.add(textToServerLabel);
        dialogVPanel.add(new HTML("<br><b>Server replies:</b>"));
        dialogVPanel.add(serverResponseLabel);
        dialogVPanel.setHorizontalAlignment(VerticalPanel.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        dialogVPanel.add(closeButton);

        final CheckBox danCheck2 = new CheckBox("Dan2");
        final LayoutPanel testPanel2 = new LayoutPanel();           //-----------> LayoutPanel
        final HorizontalPanel cont2 = new HorizontalPanel();
        final TextBox tb12 = new TextBox();
        final TextBox tb22 = new TextBox();
        final TextBox tb32 = new TextBox();

        dialogVPanel.add(danCheck2);
        testPanel2.add(cont2);
        cont2.add(tb12);
        cont2.add(tb22);
        cont2.add(tb32);

        dialogBox.setWidget(dialogVPanel);

        // Add a handler to close the DialogBox
        closeButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                dialogBox.hide();
                sendButton.setEnabled(true);
                sendButton.setFocus(true);
            }
        });

        // Create a handler for the sendButton and nameField
        class MyHandler implements ClickHandler, KeyUpHandler {
            /**
             * Fired when the user clicks on the sendButton.
             */
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                if (event.getSource().equals(sendButton)) {
                    sendNameToServer();
                }
                else if(event.getSource().equals(danCheck2)) {
                    danMethod2();
                }

            }

            /**
             * Fired when the user types in the nameField.
             */
            public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
                if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                    sendNameToServer();
                }
            }

            /**
             * Send the name from the nameField to the server and wait for a response.
             */
            private void sendNameToServer() {
                // First, we validate the input.
                errorLabel.setText("");
                String textToServer = nameField.getText();
                if (!FieldVerifier.isValidName(textToServer)) {
                    errorLabel.setText("Please enter at least four characters");
                    return;
                }

                // Then, we send the input to the server.
                sendButton.setEnabled(false);
                textToServerLabel.setText(textToServer);
                serverResponseLabel.setText("");
                greetingService.greetServer(textToServer,
                        new AsyncCallback<String>() {
                            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                                // Show the RPC error message to the user
                                dialogBox
                                        .setText("Remote Procedure Call - Failure");
                                serverResponseLabel
                                        .addStyleName("serverResponseLabelError");
                                serverResponseLabel.setHTML(SERVER_ERROR);
                                dialogBox.center();
                                closeButton.setFocus(true);
                            }

                            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                                dialogBox.setText("Remote Procedure Call");
                                serverResponseLabel
                                        .removeStyleName("serverResponseLabelError");
                                serverResponseLabel.setHTML(result);
                                dialogBox.center();
                                closeButton.setFocus(true);
                            }
                        });
            }

            private void danMethod2(){
                if (danCheck2.getValue()){
                    System.out.println("[dan]: chbCrossReferencePnr2 = Checked!");
                    testPanel2.setWidgetTopHeight(cont2, 0, PX, 60, PX);
//                  testPanel2.setHeight("60px");
                    testPanel2.animate(500);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("[dan]: chbCrossReferencePnr2 = unChecked!");
                    testPanel2.setWidgetTopHeight(cont2, 0, PX, 0, PX);
//                  testPanel2.setHeight("0px");
                    testPanel2.animate(500);
                }
            }
        }

        // Add a handler to send the name to the server
        MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
        sendButton.addClickHandler(handler);
        danCheck2.addClickHandler(handler);
        nameField.addKeyUpHandler(handler);
    }
}
```

I've tested this in the class; and it works. But when I imported it in the dialogbox, my layoutpanel (and the textbox inside) no longer shows.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I may have just missed something in my dialogbox implementation since my code works in the class.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no need for a LayoutPanel in your code. Remove it. I don't know if it solves your problem, but fewer widgets is always a good idea.

Comment: Isn't LayoutPanel needed when animating widgets? I tried removing LayoutPanel and just used the HorizontalPanel but it's not accepting the animate(). Is there an alternate way of doing it without the use of LayoutPanel (or others that implement AnimatedLayout)?

Comment: [edited] Oh, I did not notice you're the one who noted that the layoutpanel is not added hence it's not showing below. :) I've already added the layoutpanel and it works. I just missed it when I'm testing my codes. Thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LayoutPanel is never added to another widget.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I just noticed it when I'm testing Andrei's suggestion. I just missed adding the widget to dialogVPanel. I'ts now already working. :)